# iOS UITableview Scrolling stop half way

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll

When user tap on tabbar button, I need to scroll my tableview to top and I set up like this.

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController  didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
    UIViewController *vc = ((UINavigationController *)viewController).viewControllers[0];

    static UIViewController *previousController = nil;
    if (previousController == vc) {
        // the same tab was tapped a second time

        SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"scrollToTop");
        ((void (*)(id, SEL))[vc methodForSelector:selector])(vc, selector);

    }
    previousController = vc; }


- (void)scrollToTop {
    [self.tblListing setContentOffset:CGPointZero animated:NO];
}
```

Problem is that scrolling stop half way and it doesn't scroll to top. I need to tap like 2 - 3 times to scroll to top. Is there anything that I need to check? In my other projects, it is okay though. For this one, I use self-sizing cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code if you've at least one row

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
[self.tblListing scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. It is working with your suggestion. I still need to find why my content offset method is not working.

Comment: Let me check out.